# How to disable pagination in feathers service?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs

Hi I try populate my datatable using feathers service in this way:

```
app.service('pupils').find({}, (error, result) => {

    $('#pupils > table').DataTable({
        "pageLength": view.short,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "info" : false,
        "responsive": true,
        "data": result.data,
        "deferRender": true,
        "columns": [ ... ]
    });

});
```

I have more than 100 testing records but in callback I receive only 10 records.
I receive more records after added below code in feathers service:

```
paginate: {
   default: 100,
   max: 200
 }
```

but I would like to disable pagination for received all records from mongo.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To disable pagination, remove the `paginate` option. Not recommended for production however since it might bring down both, the client and the server if you try to send many thousands of records.

Note: the response object changes depending on whether you are using pagination:

**Response with pagination:** object with `data` array property

```
{
   total: 572,
   limit: 50,
   skip: 4,
   data: [/* the data is here */]
}
```

**Response without pagination:** the data array

```
[/* the data is here */]
```

Comment: If I disable pagination I receive empty array. I use datatables in my project. I need receive all records from my database, unless you know better solution? `pagination: false`, not works for me.

Comment: Then it's either a bug or something else is wrong in your setup. Removing the `paginate` option or setting it to `false` should work.

Comment: I know what was wrong. If I used paginate option my result was: `Object { total: 11, limit: 100, skip: 0, data: Array[11] }` without this option or `paginate: false` I recived Array `[ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 1 more… ]` in my datatable I had to change result.data to result. Thanks Daff!

Answer (score 3):

As [@daff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120513/daff) already pointed out in the answer above, you can disable Pagination in your configuration, although this is really not recommended.

Also you can disable pagination for a service call once in the service call.

```
service.find({ paginate:false})
```

This was discussed on Github [here](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/219)

The documentation for this feature can be found [here](https://github.com/feathersjs/docs/blob/3f68bee2f01012e81926e54791107635f8b94dea/databases/pagination.md)

Answer (score 0):

to disable Pagination on the service, you need to pass pagination as false on the service file.

```js
const options = {
    Model: createModel(app),
    paginate: false,
};
```